# Is this running plan a good idea?

Tags: running

So, what I've been doing is this:

On a treadmill, run .1 MPH faster and .05 miles further than I did last time, every other day.

The problem is, my calves are often sore for several days; at 210, I probably qualify as a heavier runner.

Does anyone know if it safe/effective for me to use this ramp up plan?  Should I wait until I am no longer sore to continue?  Should I run each speed/distance combination more than once?

Comment: There's a few other good questions along those lines as well with some plans and approaches.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?  If it is endurance, extend the TIME you are running by 5 min/week.  If you are happy with the time, you can speed up the pace.  Try and check your heart rate to gauge your level of exertion.  If you get pain google the symptoms - you may have shin splints or ITB or other issues which may require different shoes or specific stretching or other exercises (slant board, yoga stretch band...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you run ~6mph, you're not adding very much daily, maybe 30 seconds. That shouldn't be an issue, no. What will affect it, however, is how far/fast you're running, and how long you've been running for. Second is how frequently you follow this plan.

If you just started a week ago, your calves will not be used to the exercise and will be unused to the change, therefore taking longer to recover while being in a little more pain. Just stretch it out, and try not to run more than once every couple days. Which is the second point, if you're running 5 days in a row, your body won't have ample time to recover. I'd suggest 3-4 days a week, if you need to supplement other cardio, walking or cycling can be assisted without the same high impact exercises as running.

I wouldn't say 210 is on the heavier side either, that shouldn't affect you too too much. Your calves are most likely sore because you're not allowing enough time for recovery between runs, or you're still in the beginning stages. If you'd like any other info, feel free to give a little more insight and I'd be happy to give more specific advice!